# Probe Request Channel Information

Tags: ieee-802.11, wireshark

I have used wireshark to capture Wi-fi frames, and have configured my AP to operate on Channel 1.

Now in one of the transactions that occur, I find my mobile device sending a probe request in the form of a broadcast. In the middle column of Wireshark, under 802.11 radio information I find the channel listed as 1, but under 802.11 wireless lan and tag DS parameter set , the "current channel" is listed as 9.

Which of these channels is the probe request actually being sent on?.

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The channel on which the probe request was captured is specified under the 802.11 radio information.
The "DS parameter" is an information element parameter optionally present in beacons and probe request & response (cf. §9.4.2.4 "DSSS Parameter Set element" of the IEEE802.11-2016 standard).